# Por que esse laço "for" não é infinito?

Tags: java, loop, for

```
public class Loop {
public static void main(String[] a) {
int cont=0;
for (int i=0; i>=0; i+=2, cont++);
System.out.println("cont:"+cont); }}
```

Me chamou a atenção a condição do laço for `i>=0`. Na hora pensei: *loop* infinito, porém o código compilou e imprimiu na tela o valor `cont`: 1073741824

Por que o laço `for` do referido código não é infinito?

O valor da variável cont deve-se pelo incremento é claro, mas quantas iterações o laço `for` fez para atribuir tal valor à variável `cont`?

Obs.: O código estava exatamente assim, sem indentação.

Comment: Pq chega uma hora que vai estourar o `int` basicamente. Quando o contador dele passar do limite, ele volta pro "outro lado". Pense num odômetro de carro, quando a quilometragem passa do que cabe nele, ele volta pro começo (que no caso do int começa em -valor e vai até +valor)

Comment: @Bacco Claroo! 2.147.483.647 valor máximo, segundo vi aqui, porém sabe alguma bibliografia que cite esse overflow em estrutura de repetição?

Comment: A estrutura é irrelevante pro problema, até pq normalmente não se usa isso assim (tem cara de exercicio, alguém aproveitou esse "efeito colateral" e criou um cenário para mostrar - raras situações poderiam tirar benefício real disso) - Normalmente você tem que conhecer esses limites para evitar bugs, não para explorar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vou te mostrar um código C#:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        for (int i = 1; i >= 0; i *= 2) { WriteLine($"i: {i}"); }
        checked {
            for (int j = 1; j >= 0; j *= 2) { WriteLine($"j: {j}"); }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Bh9GWM). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/strfFd). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/IntOverflow.cs).

Não faço com Java porque ele não pode controlar a verificação de *overflow*.

Por padrão ela é desligada, então quando você chega em um valor acima da capacidade que o tipo `int` suporta ele continua operando normalmente só que há uma troca de sinal que é um bit no número. Por questão de performance não é verificado se isto ocorre. Sendo negativo o laço encerra.

O segundo que eu fiz liga a verificação, fica mais lento porque toda mudança da variável tem que ver se não estourou, mas aí um erro acaba ocorrendo porque o processador indica que a operação é inválida e o .NET captura isto e informação a execução.

Mas pode [ver em Java também](https://ideone.com/kxwdOh). Eu mudei para multiplicar por 2 para entrar em progressão geométrica e encerrar mais rapidamente. Também poderia ter começado por um número maior.

O tamanho máximo do `int` é 2.147.483.647 (2 elevado à 31 já que ele tem 32 bits e um deles é usado como sinal). O valor mínimo é -2,147,483,648.

Assim entra em *loop* infinito:

```
class Loop {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        int cont = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000000000000000L; i *= 2, cont++) { System.out.println("i:" + i); }
        System.out.println("cont:"+cont);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KDawrA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lsdafzff-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/IntOverflow.java).

Answer (score -1):

O tipo int tem um limite máximo.
Ao chegar nesse limite, o laço é finalizado.

`int = 4 bytes - 32 bits = -2147483648 a + 2147483647 - números inteiros`